# Convert JSON to JAVA by jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse json data retrieved from google custom search.

Here is the json example:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "link": "address1"
  },
  {
   "link": "address2"
  }
 ]
}
```

And this is the POJO:

```
public class Result 
{
    item[] items;
    class item
    {
        String link;
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

**Unrecognized field "items" (Class Result), not marked as ignorable**

What wrong with my POJO?

Comment: Probably that the class item is an inner class... Try making it a public class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the class structure like below

```
class item {
    String link;
}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class Result {
    item[] items;
}
```

The @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) will be help full if there is any properties in JSON string but that is not in your class then parser won't through any exception it will simply ignore it.

EDIT:
Complete code with Example

```
class Item {
    String link;

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Result {
    List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
```

}

```
public class JsonCommonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String data = "{\"items\": [{\"link\": \"address1\"},{\"link\": \"address2 \"}]}";
        Result result = mapper.readValue(data, Result.class);
        System.out.println(result.items.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: @JsonIgnoreProperties has nothing to do with his particular problem. While its true that the json from google custom search has other fields, his problem is that his `item` class is an inner class that is not static.

Comment: Yes By thinking Google result I given that idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you use inner class in jackson the inner class must be static or don't use inner class.